# F-curve modifier not working

Tags: fcurves

Tried to apply noise F-curve modifier on the power of a light but it isn't showing up on graph editor. Not sure what the problem could be.

Comment: go to View > View Selected (or View All) or post a screen (...blend)

Answer (score 1):

- with *Light* selected go to *Properties editor > Data Properties > Power* add keyframe
- go to *Graph Editor > View > View Selected* (or *View All*)
- if selected add *Noise* modifier

[image]

Comment: The keyframe is not showing up on the graph editor even though I have it selected and I cant see the squiggly red noise line either. I'm guessing those are linked.

Comment: As I wrote, if this is not the case please attach the blend file via https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ (follow instructions)

Answer (score 0):

Try "View Frame Selected" and hit the single Keyframe (black dot). I ran into this problem as well and received the menu through this.